# PHP: Nested loop with only unique pairs

Tags: php, loops

I need to create an array of only unique pairs so there are no duplicates.
The problem is that when just iterating over each other, for some reason last pair usually is duplicate.

So here's a quick example:

```php
<?php 

$teams = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
    ['id' => 4],
];

foreach ($teams as $team_a) {
    foreach ($teams as $team_b) {
        if ($team_a['id'] !== $team_b['id']) {
            $pairs[] = [$team_a['id'], $team_b['id']];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Returns something like this:

```
0: [1, 2]
1: [1, 3]
2: [1, 4]
3: [2, 1]
4: [2, 3]
5: [2, 4]
6: [3, 1]
7: [3, 2]
8: [3, 4]
...
```

So you can see that some pairs are the same, like `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`. And after the half iterations there are only repeats.

What would be the most efficient way to iterate like this and be sure that there are only unique pairs?

Thanks!

Comment: this code.. what are you actually trying to do here? Why are you looping twice for arrays of single-level arrays?

Comment: I don't get this pairs? Everyone got to play against team 10?

Comment: My bad, didn't even look to what I wrote when making an example. I edited it. I need to create a score like table where every team plays against each other and I'm really not sure how to write it properly... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the duplicate always appears when key(team_a) > key(team_b)

```
<?php 

$teams = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
    ['id' => 4],
];

foreach ($teams as $offset => $team_a) {
    foreach (array_slice($teams, $offset+1) as $team_b) {
        $pairs[] = [$team_a['id'], $team_b['id']];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could to do this with recursion instead of two for each loops.

```
<?php

$teams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10];

getMatchup($teams);

function getMatchUp($teams, $matches = [], $start = 0) {
    // Check if the whole array has been checked
    if ($start == count($teams)) {
        return var_dump($matches);
    }
    // Check every option considering a certain start point
    for ($x = $start; $x < count($teams); $x++) {

        // As long the team is not the same, add to matches
        if ($start !== $x) {
            $matches[] = [$teams[$start] => $teams[$x]];
        }
    }
    // First team has been matched up, start matching the second team and so on..
    getMatchup($teams,$matches, $start + 1);
}
```

Running example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4277d966c4ceacdbe7024d14fb03fe05fd760471

Comment: It isnt necesary to introduce recursion.

Comment: You are right, it is possible i'm sorry. editted the text above

Comment: Btw, every recursive algorithm can be written without recursion using explicit stack. And most recursive algorithms can be optimized beyond that. Only good reason to write recursive algorithms recursively is to prove a concept. They are easier to write and understand, but they will never perform better.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and noticing me being slowpoke :)